# Filtering pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm reading in a .csv file using pandas, and then I want to filter out the rows where a specified column's value is not in a dictionary for example. So something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index_col=0, 
    names=['col1', 'col2','col3','col4']) 

c = df.col4.value_counts(normalize=True).head(20)
values = dict(zip(c.index.tolist()[1::2], c.tolist()[1::2])) # Get odd and create dict

df_filtered = filter out all rows where col4 not in values
```

After searching around a bit I tried using the following to filter it:

```
df_filtered = df[df.col4 in values]
```

but that unfortunately didn't work.

I've done the following to make it works for what I want to do, but it's incredibly slow for a large .csv file, so I thought there must be a way to do it that's built in to pandas:

```
t = [(list(df.col1) + list(df.col2) + list(df.col3)) for i in range(len(df.col4)) if list(df.col4)[i] in values]
```

Comment: Using the `in` operator against a `dict` only checks for keys. Perhaps you meant to use a `set`?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check against the dictionary values:

```
df_filtered = df[df.col4.isin(values.values())]
```

If you want to check against the dictionary keys:

```
df_filtered = df[df.col4.isin(values.keys())]
```

Answer (score 0):

As A.Kot mentioned you could use the values method of the `dict` to search. But the `values` method returns either a `list` or an iterator depending on your version of Python.

If your only reason for creating that `dict` is membership testing, and you only ever look at the values of the `dict` then you are using the wrong data structure.

A [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) will improve your lookup performance, and simplify your check back to:

```
df_filtered = df[df.col4 in values]
```

If you use values elsewhere, and you want to check against the keys, then you're ok because membership testing against keys is efficient.